# jquery validation another page is not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have used jquery validation. My js code is like this in register.php file.
It works fine and validation is done. But when I place this code in separate file 'something.js' and include this in script tag but it does not work.

```js
<script>
$(function()
{
$("#form1").validate(
      {
        rules: 
        {
          user: 
          {
            required: true
          },
          email: 
          {
            required: true,
            email: true
          }
        },
        messages: 
        {
          user: 
          {
            required: " Please enter your name"
          },
          email: 
          {
            required: " Please enter your email address.",
   email: "Please enter valid email address"
          }
        }
      }); 
});   
</script>
```

Comment: are you leaving off the script tags when you place this in something.js? are you sure you have the path to something.js correct in the src attribute?

Comment: sorry... I am new @ stack overflow.

Comment: yes.. it is correct. i have tested it.

Comment: it's ok, welcome to SO! what do you mean it is correct and you've tested it. you're not experiencing a problem anymore?

Comment: is there any $(function... issue ??

Comment: Can you edit your question and add how you are including something.js? Did you load the JQuery Library before you included your script? In the `<head>` tags or within the `<body>`? There are multiple reasons why your script may not be working and the information you've provided isn't enough to determine the problem.